# What does the CookieAuthenticationOptions.LogoutPath property do in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In ASP.NET Core 2.1, can anyone explain what the `CookieAuthenticationOptions.LogoutPath` does? Per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.logoutpath?view=aspnetcore-2.1) it says:

> If the LogoutPath is provided the handler then a request to that path will redirect based on the ReturnUrlParameter.

But I don't even think that sentence has proper grammar, so I'm confused by the meaning.

In `Startup.cs`, I have it set like this:

```
// Added after AddMvc()
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LogoutPath = $"/account/logout";
});
```

1. When will this be called?
2. Do I need to create a corresponding `GET` action in my `AccountController` and View for this? Or will a `POST` action work? For example:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
   {
       await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
   ```
3. Does my Logout action need to sign the user out or will they have already been signed out by that point?

Comment: When you log out, the browser will redirect to this URL passing the return URL in the query string.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `LogoutPath` that you can configure with the cookie authentication scheme is an odd one. While the `LoginPath` has a direct effect and is basically the URL that the end user is being redirected to when the cookie authentication is challenged, the `LogoutPath` is not used directly.

Instead, the configured `LogoutPath` is just being used to validate the current URL when a sign-out happens with the cookie authentication scheme. The [check looks like this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/2.1.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L368-L370):

```
// Only redirect on the logout path
var shouldRedirect = Options.LogoutPath.HasValue && OriginalPath == Options.LogoutPath;
await ApplyHeaders(shouldRedirect, context.Properties);
```

So this basically checks whether the `OriginalPath` which is the current request’s path is equal to the configured logout path. If that’s the case, then the `ApplyHeaders` call will perform a redirect to the `RedirectUri` of the authentication properties.

The purpose of this is to make sure that a redirect back to a path can only happen when the real logout URL is being accessed. So for example, if the user clicks the logout button, they might get logged out and then redirected back to where they come from. But if they are logged out elsewhere, then they are not redirected back automatically since only the logout URL is considered a safe place to redirect the user back.

The same logic exists for the `LoginPath` too btw. but there is the additional logic that the cookie authentication scheme will also redirect *to* that URL when the scheme is challenged (e.g. when authentication is required through an authorize filter).

> Do I need to create a corresponding GET action in my `AccountController` and View for this? Or will a POST action work?

That’s up to you and how you want to handle the logout. For the above logic to run, you just need *any* action on that route, so you can also do a POST to require users to perform a form submission in order to sign them out (to prevent accidental sign out through GET requests).

> Does my Logout action need to sign the user out or will they have already been signed out by that point?

You will have to call the `SignOutAsync` yourself since there is no implicit handling for these routes. Just like you also need to implement your own login logic on the `LoginPath`, you also need to implement the logout logic.

The configured paths are really just for the cookie scheme to know *where* those routes are, but they do not have any impact on their behavior.

Comment: That means, if I configure the LogoutPath the middleware will do the redirect for me (if ReturnUrl is provided) and if not, I'd have to do that in my logout action. That's all - correct?

Comment: The middleware will only do the redirect *back* from the logout path, but not towards the logout path. So, e.g. if your logout action called `SignOutAsync` and passed a `RedirectUri`, then the cookie scheme would automatically redirect back to that `RedirectUri` once it completes. But you will still have to provide something for the user to click on to actually get to your logout action.