# Redirect after sign-out through OpenID Connect not working

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I am building a Blazor Server ASP.NET Core application with cookie based authentication through a OpenID Connect (OIDC) provider. On sign-out I want to be redirected to localhost URI: https://localhost:44378/signout-oidc. This is the path registrered as Post Logout Redirect URI at the OIDC Provider.

When I sign-out I am sent through the sign-out flow at the Connect provider, their log states "End session request validation success", but I end up on the URI: https://localhost:44378/signout-oidc?state=CfDJ8LdQ[...] which is a blank page. If I try to access https://localhost:44378/signout-oidc while I am logged in I get ***Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Error: The remote signout request was ignored because the 'sid' parameter was missing, which may indicate an unsolicited logout.***

I have tried a myriad of different combinations of overriding the `SignedOutRedirectUri`, `SignedOutCallbackPath`, `RemoteSignOutPath`, etc., as well as redirecting to other pages - all to no avail. I am running out of ideas and would appreciate all kinds of input.

I have added the code for the configuration of OpenID authentication:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;  
            })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration.GetSection("AuthorizationStrings")["Authority"];
            options.ClientId = configuration.GetSection("AuthorizationStrings")["ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = configuration.GetSection("AuthorizationStrings")["ClientSecret"];
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { NameClaimType = "name" };
            options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-oidc";
```

Code for the sign-out flow which is initiated through a sign-out button. The formatting of the Redirect URI is how the OIDC provider expects it (the state parameter is optional so I have left it out):

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var ac = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
            String uri = String.Format("[CONNECT PROVIDER URI]/endsession?id_token_hint={0}&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://localhost:44378/signout-oidc", ac);            
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var prop = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = uri
            };   
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc", prop);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the LogoutPath, as it must match the URL of the "Logout" link; if they do match, then the RedirectUri will be accepted.

```
}).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
    ...
});
```

See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52709492/what-does-the-cookieauthenticationoptions-logoutpath-property-do-in-asp-net-core) for more details.

This is my Logout code for /User/Logout

```
/// <summary>
/// Do the logout  
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");

    //Important, this method should never return anything.
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this doesnt change anything - would a LogoutPath stored in cookies be able to overrule a Post Logout Redirect Uri? I might lack some general knowledge of the flow happening here

Comment: The cookie itself is not involved here and for the redirect to work, I added the code I use to signout a user to my answer.

Comment: When I change the method not to return the result of of the Signout from the OpenIdConnect server, it does not hit this breakpoint in my Startup:
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context.Request);
                };
And it does not redirect to the auth server.

Comment: You need to replace "CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme" with the name of your cookie handler "Cookies" and OpenIdConnectDefaults with "oidc", updated my answer.